# Удаление элемента из списка при условии C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть некий список, в котором находятся обьекты. К примеру есть тигр, рыба,...,
Условие должно выглядеть так ( Если в списке есть тигр || рыба , то одна из рыб удаляется)
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете

Comment: Что значит «есть тигр || рыба»? Если список состоит из одного тигра, условие выполняется? И да, каким образом вы кодируете ваших животных, отличается рыба от тигра типом или значением поля/свойства?

Comment: Подобное можно сделать кучей разных способов и хорошо бы конкретно знать, что вы хотите(входные данные, выходные данные). В приведенном условии я логики не вижу, т.к. рыба удаляется просто по факту своего существования и тигр тут не при чем.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9KQYzK9r   Чтобы можно было понять суть программы я сделал вырезки из кода

Comment: @ВиталийБирюков, хорошо, проблема вашего условия в том, что оно не полное. Допустим в контейнере есть 12 тигров и 5 рыб, что должно быть на выходе? Пропадает только одна рыба? Пропадают все 5 рыб? Или пропадает 5 рыб и 7 тигров, которым не досталась рыба? Формализуйте свою задачу полностью, ведь от этого зависит способ решения. Если в контейнере только по одному экземпляру, надо это указать и решение ниже уже написано.

Comment: @AlexKrass Да, простите,я просто хотел узнать необходимый  минимум. Пропадет 5 рыб и 7 тигров ( если у меня в св-вах тигра прописано, что ему достаточно сьесть 1 рыбу\цикл, чтоб не умереть ). Моя задача посмотреть через сколько циклов в контейнере никого не останется.

Comment: @ВиталийБирюков, количество рыб поделенное на количество тигров с округлением в большую сторону)) А так посмотрите в сторону Linq, там очень продвинутые методы работы с коллекциями: `Select`, `Where`, `Take`, `Any`, `Remove`, `Count` etc. которые упрощают работу, что бы не залезать в циклы. Правда, что бы его изучить на хорошем уровне, тоже надо время.

Comment: А если в списке только рыба - цикл будет крутиться вечно? И код стоит вставить в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть только тигр, то удалять всё равно нечего. Значит просто ищем первую рыбу и удаляем. Например, через [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx), а внутри предиката уже проверяем. Ну или ищем индекс, а потом по нему удаляем.

Comment: А если рыбки или тигра нет? Я хотел сделать примерно такую проверку, но нигде наити не могу ( примерно вот так - if ( animals.contain (new tiger ) !=0 // если в списке есть хотя бы один тигр || animals.contain (new fish)!=0// и есть рыбка - то -

Comment: @ВиталийБирюков, для проверки на наличие чего-то в коллекции можно пройтись циклом `for` или `Linq`. Только условие тогда должно быть не или `||`, а и `&&`. И тигр и рыбка. Можно воспользоваться LINQ для примера: `if(list.Any(p => p is Tiger) list.Remove(list.FirstOrDefault(p => p is Fish))`

Comment: @ВиталийБирюков, то удалять нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я за явный код и минимум экономии на строках.

```
public interface ICreature
{
    long Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class STiger : ICreature
{
    public long? DiedOnCycle;

    long ICreature.Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SFish : ICreature
{
    public long? EatenOnCycle;

    long ICreature.Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SCycleResult
{
    public List<STiger> StarvedTigers;
    public List<SFish> EatenFish;

    public SCycleResult()
    {
        this.StarvedTigers = new List<STiger>();
        this.EatenFish = new List<SFish>();
    }
}

public class CContainer
{
    private int cycle;
    private List<ICreature> content;

    //Исполнение цикла.
    public static SCycleResult CycleExecute(CContainer iContainer)
    {
        SCycleResult result = new SCycleResult();

        int creatureIndex = 0;
        List<Tuple<STiger, int>> hungryTigers = new List<Tuple<STiger, int>>();
        List<Tuple<SFish, int>> availableFish = new List<Tuple<SFish, int>>();

        int newCycleIndex = iContainer.cycle + 1;

        List<int> casualties = new List<int>();

        //Пробежаться по заповеднику.
        while (creatureIndex < iContainer.content.Count)
        {
            ICreature nextCreature = iContainer.content[creatureIndex];
            nextCreature.Age++;

            //Киска или рыбка?
            if (nextCreature is STiger)
            {
                STiger tiger = nextCreature as STiger;

                //Есть ли что покушать?
                if (availableFish.Count > 0)
                {
                    Tuple<SFish, int> food = availableFish[0];
                    availableFish.RemoveAt(0);

                    food.Item1.EatenOnCycle = newCycleIndex;

                    casualties.Add(food.Item2);
                    result.EatenFish.Add(food.Item1);
                }
                else
                {
                    hungryTigers.Add(new Tuple<STiger, int>(tiger, creatureIndex));
                }
            }
            else if (nextCreature is SFish)
            {
                SFish fish = nextCreature as SFish;

                //Есть ли кому скормить?
                if (hungryTigers.Count > 0)
                {
                    Tuple<STiger, int> eater = hungryTigers[0];
                    hungryTigers.RemoveAt(0);

                    fish.EatenOnCycle = newCycleIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    availableFish.Add(new Tuple<SFish, int>(fish, creatureIndex));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Неопознанный живой объект.
                Exception clsUnknownCreature = new ApplicationException("Обнаружено неизвестное существо.");
                clsUnknownCreature.Data.Add("creatureIndex", creatureIndex);
                clsUnknownCreature.Data.Add("nextCreature", nextCreature);
                clsUnknownCreature.Data.Add("iContainer", iContainer);
                throw clsUnknownCreature;
            }

            creatureIndex++;
        }

        //Были голодные - стали холодные.
        foreach (Tuple<STiger, int> doomedTiger in hungryTigers)
        {
            doomedTiger.Item1.DiedOnCycle = newCycleIndex;
            result.StarvedTigers.Add(doomedTiger.Item1);
            casualties.Add(doomedTiger.Item2);
        }

        //Чистим по индексу, так что надо аккуратно.
        casualties.Sort();

        //Убрать ошмётки рыбы и/или истощенные трупы.
        for (int casualtyIndex = casualties.Count - 1; casualtyIndex >= 0; casualtyIndex--)
        {
            iContainer.content.RemoveAt(casualties[casualtyIndex]);
        }

        iContainer.cycle++;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Не тестил, это уж вы сами.